# How to downsample images correctly?

Tags: android, bitmap, decode, downsampling, pixelate

### Background

Creating an app that has a lot of high quality images, I've decided to downscale the images to the needed size (meaning that if the image is larger than the screen , I downscale it ) .

### The problem

I've noticed that on some devices, if the images are downscaled, they become blurry/pixelated, yet on the same devices, for the same target imageView size, if the images aren't downscaled, they look just fine.

### What I've tried

I've decided to check this issue further, and created a small POC app that shows the issue.

Before showing you code, here's a demo of what I'm talking about :

[image]

it's a bit hard to see the difference, but you can see that the second is a bit pixelated . this can be shown on any image.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
  {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView originalImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.originalImageView);
    final ImageView halvedImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.halvedImageView);
    final ImageView halvedBitmapImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.halvedBitmapImageView);
    //
    final Bitmap originalBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test);
    originalImageView.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
    halvedImageView.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
    //
    final LayoutParams layoutParams=halvedImageView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width=originalBitmap.getWidth()/2;
    layoutParams.height=originalBitmap.getHeight()/2;
    halvedImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    //
    final Options options=new Options();
    options.inSampleSize=2;
    // options.inDither=true; //didn't help
    // options.inPreferQualityOverSpeed=true; //didn't help
    final Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.test,options);
    halvedBitmapImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
  }
```

xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">


      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="original" />

      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/originalImageView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="original , imageView size is halved" />

      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/halvedImageView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="bitmap size is halved" />

      <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/halvedBitmapImageView" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

### The question

Why does it occur?

Both methods should have the same result, as both sample from the same source and using the same factor.

I've tried to play with the downsampling method, but nothing has helped.

Using the inDensity (instead of inSampleSize) seems to fix it, but I'm not sure what to set for it . i think that for outside images (from the internet for example), i can set it to the screen density multiplied by the sample size i wish to use.

But is it even a good solution? what should i do in the case the images are inside the resources folder (i don't think there is a function to get which density folder a bitmap is located at) ? why does it work while using the recommended way (talked about [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)) doesn't work well ?

---

EDIT: I've found out a trick to get which density is used for a drawable you get from the resources ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8577411/878126)) . however, it isn't future proof, as you need to be specific to the density to detect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ok, i've found a nice alternative, which i think should work for any kind of bitmap decoding.

not only that, but it also allows you to downscale using any sample size you wish, and not just the power of 2 . if you put more effort to it, you can even use fractions instead of integers for the downscaling.

the code below works for images from the res folder, but it can easily be done for any kind of bitmap decoding:

```
private Bitmap downscaleBitmapUsingDensities(final int sampleSize,final int imageResId)
  {
  final Options bitmapOptions=new Options();
  bitmapOptions.inDensity=sampleSize;
  bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=1;
  final Bitmap scaledBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),imageResId,bitmapOptions);
  scaledBitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
  return scaledBitmap;
  }
```

i've tested it and it shows the downsampled images just fine. in the image below, i've shown the original image, and downscaling the image using teh inSampleSize method, and using my method.

it's hard to see the difference, but the one that uses the density actually doesn't just skip pixels, but uses all of them to take into account. it might be a bit slower, but it's more precise and uses a nicer interpolation.

[image]

the only disadvantage compared to using the inSampleSize seems to be speed, which is better on inSampleSize because inSampleSize skips pixels and because the densities method does extra calculations on the skipped pixels.

However, i think that somehow android runs both methods in about the same speed.

I think the 2 methods comparison is similar to the comparison between the [nearest-neighbor downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest-neighbor_interpolation) and the [bilinear-interpolation downsampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).

EDIT: i've found one downside of the method i've shown here, compared to the one Google has . the memory used during the process can be quite high, and i think it depends on the image itself. this means you should use it only on cases you think make sense.

---

EDIT: i've made a merged solution (both google's solution and mine) for those who wish to overcome the memory problem. it's not perfect, but it's better than what i did before, because it won't use as much memory as the original bitmap needs during the downsampling. instead, it will use the memory as used in google's solution.

here's the code:

```
    // as much as possible, use google's way to downsample:
    bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    bitmapOptions.inDensity = 1;
    bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;
    while (bitmapOptions.inSampleSize * 2 <= inSampleSize)
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize *= 2;

    // if google's way to downsample isn't enough, do some more :
    if (bitmapOptions.inSampleSize != inSampleSize) 
      {
      // downsample by bitmapOptions.inSampleSize/originalSampleSize .
      bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = bitmapOptions.inSampleSize;
      bitmapOptions.inDensity = inSampleSize;
      } 
    else if(sampleSize==1)
      {
      bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=preferHeight ? reqHeight : reqWidth;
      bitmapOptions.inDensity=preferHeight ? height : width;
      }
```

so, in short, the pros and cons of both methods:

Google's way (using inSampleSize) uses less memory during decoding, and is faster.
However, it causes some graphical artifacts sometimes and it only supports downsampling to the power of 2, so the result bitmap might take more than what you wanted (for example size of x1/4 instead of x1/7) .

My way (using densities) is more precise, gives higher quality images, and uses less memory on the result bitmap. 
However, it can use a lot of memory during the decoding (depends on the input) and it's a bit slower.

---

EDIT: another improvement, as I've found that on some cases the output image doesn't match the required size restriction, and you don't wish to downsample too much using Google's way :

```
    final int newWidth = width / bitmapOptions.inSampleSize, newHeight = height / bitmapOptions.inSampleSize;
    if (newWidth > reqWidth || newHeight > reqHeight) {
        if (newWidth * reqHeight > newHeight * reqWidth) {
            // prefer width, as the width ratio is larger
            bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = reqWidth;
            bitmapOptions.inDensity = newWidth;
        } else {
            // prefer height
            bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = reqHeight;
            bitmapOptions.inDensity = newHeight;
        }
    }
```

So, for example, downsampling from 2448x3264 image to 1200x1200, it will become 900x1200

Comment: failing for image with dimensions greater then 2xxx,3xxx

Comment: @Farhan can you please describe the failure? what exactly happens when you try to do it? do you get OOM ?

Comment: actually, normally i use opts.inSampleSize = sample.. so that line(opts.inDensity = sample) really got my attention, your code does work but when i used image of high resolution, it just didn't decode it correctly. no exception but no image.. i can re test and paste more detailed results if you say...

Comment: @Farhan odd. i would expect something to show... was the image downloaded from the internet to the device, or does it reside in the resources folder? if so, in which folder and can you please upload it somehow so that i can check it out?

Comment: @Farhan i've updated my answer. seems that if you have a huge image, only during the downsampling process itself, it will take a lot of memory. after the process is done, however, you get the exact expected size and expected memory usage.

Comment: @Farhan i've made a merged solution. it should help in most cases.

Comment: @androiddeveloper reacting a bit late here, but I'm not comfortable with how to use the last two code snippets. They are all alone, without any method signature. For instance, what is `width` and `height` in the last one ? Is it the image's dimensions ? If so, do we need to preload it to get the dimensions, then load it again with these parameters ? I'm kinda lost here....

Comment: @PaulW Yes, Image decoding usually takes two phases: get information about it (resolution etc...) and then the decoding into a real Bitmap that you can actually show. The width&height (taken from bitmapOptions in the first step)  is of the original Bitmap, if you don't downsample at all. If you don't take the first step, you would end up with the same size as the original, which takes more memory than if you don't downsample into a smaller resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using inSampleSize. To figure what sample size you should use, do the following.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
int originalHeight = options.outHeight;
int originalWidth = options.outWidth;
// Calculate your sampleSize based on the requiredWidth and originalWidth
// For e.g you want the width to stay consistent at 500dp
int requiredWidth = 500 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int sampleSize = originalWidth / requiredWidth;
// If the original image is smaller than required, don't sample
if(sampleSize < 1) { sampleSize = 1; }
options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
options.inPurgeable = true;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), options);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: as i've already written in the question (including showing it in code) i used inSampleSize , and it causes pixelated problems when using it compared to normal resizing of the imageView. the question was why , and if there is a way to fix it.

Comment: The image you have posted to show the difference is not loading.

Comment: i have no idea why you can't see the image. maybe you block it? have you tried other web browsers? maybe on your mobile?

Comment: I see it now. Of course, the image is going to look better if the imageView is halved with the image the same. If you half the image and half the imageView, it is going to look the same the original image. The original image is as pixelated as the last image. If you want the quality to be good, then use a smaller inSampleSize which can be achieved by increasing the requiredWidth. Increase the requiredWidth by 20% more than what you need, the image will look better. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: the inSampleSize cannot be less than 2. in fact i think it must be a power of 2 (meaning 2,4,8,16,...) . and it's not an obvious thing as both the smaller imageView and using the density technique i've written at the bottom have the image look better. please read the entire question and think about it.

Comment: inSampleSize can be 1, in fact that's the default value. And 1 is a power of 2, it's 2 to the 0th power.

Answer (score 0):

For me, only downscaling using inSampleSize performed well (but not like nearest neighbor algorithm). But unfortunately, this doesn't allow to get the exact resolution that we need (just exactly integer times smaller than the original).

So I found that SonyMobile's solution of this problem works the best for such task.

Briefly, it consists of 2 steps:

1. downscale using ***BitmapFactory.Options::inSampleSize->BitmapFactory.decodeResource()*** as close as possible to the resolution that you need but not less than it
2. get to the exact resolution by downscaling a little bit using ***Canvas::drawBitmap()***

Here is detailed explanation how SonyMobile resolved this task: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Here is the source code of SonyMobile scale utils: http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/code-example-module/image-scaling-code-example-for-android/

Comment: They are just scaling the bitmap that you've got after decoding. this is called downscaling, and not downsampling. This is in fact what I also do in JNI in my library here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/AndroidJniBitmapOperations . Anyway, The question was about downsampling, meaning you decode the bitmap directly from the inputStream to a bitmap of the size you wanted. Sadly, I think the solution I've found (using "inTargetDensity") is also doing the same thing - using 2 bitmaps at the same time, though it's hidden from whoever use it.

Comment: Yes, you're right=) But when I tried settings:  bitmapOptions.inDensity=sampleSize; and 
  bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity=1; looked like Android used nearest neigbor downscaling/sampling algorithm :(

Comment: I think it uses both on this case- first the nearest neigbor, and then the other one. BTW, I just call it this way because of what I see that comes out as the output image. if the target image size isn't in the power of 2 (for example, downsample by 5), it should use both methods. Maybe you just don't notice it? Try using only my original method (when inSampleSize==1) , and then try the merged method I've suggested later, and see if there is a noticeble difference. In any case, the merged method tries to enjoy both worlds.

Comment: But this means that there is now way in Android to scale/downsample an image/bitmap from one resolution to a smaller without using nearest neigbor algorithm? It's so strange - definitely they have such way at least when they draw ImageView it's downscaled/sampled not that bad to any resolution...

Comment: You can always use your own algorithm. I have implemented the Bilinear-Interpolation when I was at the university, and it was in Java. Maybe I will put it into the JNI project I've made. Hope it still works. This should revive the code that isn't available to anyone...

Comment: Thank you, it would be great! Still fill that it's a big shame for Android not to have native good scaling (not nearest neighbor) and comfortable to use bitmap utils.

Comment: OK, I've fixed all of the issues with the C/C++ code, and soon I will publish it on Github. The post was also corrected: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230047/trying-to-convert-bilinear-interpolation-code-from-java-to-c-c-on-android#comment35540801_23230047