# SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null while working with local resources

Tags: android, performance, listview, bitmap

I have a listview which is dynamically populated with items.
Each item has image and text. I know this context is so repeating in others stackoverflow's questions. However I still can't find the solution.

First I had only this call which successfully sets each image in the listview.

```
imageview.setImageResource(getResuID());
```

Nevertheless, I wanted to optimize this, following [google training guide](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), due to slow scrolling and lag.

Then I tried to use the code from training and the problem appeared. Now I get null all around from BitmapFactory.

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424864/listview-performance-is-slow) about async task and GC and I also tried to move the scaling to the **AsyncTask** which neither solved the issue.

This is what I do:

Calling the task from "getView" in my the listview adapter which extends from BaseAdapter:

```
int resID = getResID();
AsyncImageSetter task = (AsyncImageSetter) new AsyncImageSetter(thumb_image,resID).execute();

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public class AsyncImageSetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        private ImageView img;
        private int image_resId;
        private Bitmap bmp; 

        public AsyncImageSetter(  ImageView img, int image_ResId ) {

            this.img = img;
            this.image_resId = image_ResId; 

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
             try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            bmp = (decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity.getResources(), image_resId, 100, 100)); 

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            bmp = null;

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }
```

Receiving this log messages:

```
01-07 19:57:54.167: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.167: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.277: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.277: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.277: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.306: D/dalvikvm(2141): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1247K, 12% free 10097K/11463K, paused 5ms+6ms
01-07 19:57:54.387: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.387: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.397: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.507: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.507: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.517: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.626: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
01-07 19:57:54.626: D/skia(2141): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

Is that due to GC memory free?

It's strange but if instead of

```
bmp = (decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity.getResources(), resources.getResID(), 100, 100));
```

I use

```
bmp = (decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.image1, 100, 100));
```

It works "fine". I see all listview items with repeated image though.

Also I tried to follow the BitmapFun sample to incorporate the caching, but it's really advanced sample. Maybe you could suggest me some easier way to do it without so many classes.

Thanks

Comment: hard to tell without knowing what's in `resID` in the first line. For all i know it could be a random int.

Comment: sorry. There's a simple drawable id: R.drawable.id_imageXX