# Trying to scale down a Bitmap in Android not working

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to scale down a bitmap. In short, the image is originally from a ByteArray with a width of 4016. After I scale the image down with factory options, it still reports the image with a width of 4016.

Here are two clips of my code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Object... params) {


            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            if (options.outHeight > options.outWidth) {
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 640, 960);
            } else {
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 960, 640);
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            //myImageByteArray is 4016 wide
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myImageByteArray, 0, myImageByteArray.length, options);

            //This log statement outputs 4016!!! Shouldn't it be smaller since I just decoded the byteArray with options?
            Log.d("bitmap", myBitmap.getWidth()+"");

}

        public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
                // width
                final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
                final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

                // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
                // guarantee
                // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to
                // the
                // requested height and width.
                inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

### Update:

Here are two clips of my code:

```
Bitmap myBitmap = null;
        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Object... params) {


            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            //myImageByteArray is 4016 wide
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myImageByteArray, 0, myImageByteArray.length, options);
            if (options.outHeight > options.outWidth) {
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 640, 960);
            } else {
                options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, 960, 640);
            }

            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            //myImageByteArray is 4016 wide
            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myImageByteArray, 0, myImageByteArray.length, options);

            //This log statement outputs around 1000 now. 
            Log.d("bitmap", myBitmap.getWidth()+"");

}

        public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
            // Raw height and width of image
            final int height = options.outHeight;
            final int width = options.outWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

                // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
                // width
                final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
                final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

                // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
                // guarantee
                // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to
                // the
                // requested height and width.
                inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.decodeByteArray(..)` twice! Once to attain the width and the height with `.inJustDecodeBounds` set to `true` and then again with `.inSampleSize` to get the actual scaled Bitmap, `options.outHeight` and `options.outWidth` in your code are probably zero.

call `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(myImageByteArray, 0, myImageByteArray.length, options);` before checking `outHeight` and `outWidth`.

#### Edit

Take a look at this example from [Google's Android Dev site](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

Notice that `options.outHeight` is used **after** calling `decodeResources(...)`. This you have to fix in your code.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer. Can you explain it further?

Comment: I posted an update. I just added one single line. Hopefully that is what you meant. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Yep! Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. I was confused at your first answer because I thought you needed me to do two seperate things to fix it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't fill the bitmapOptions with anything that will set its "outHeight" and "outWidth".

you should check out the bitmap tutorials of google:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

in order to decide what is the value to scale to, you need to know the size of the image compared to the destination size. that's why you need to do decoding twice.

btw, there is another way to downsample images, as i've shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408505/how-to-downscale-images-correctly).