# How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while loading the activity

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-view, image-loading

Every time I load certain activity called ProductActivity, I encounter the following error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 15694612 byte allocation with 2874400 free bytes and 2MB until OOM
       at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(VMRuntime.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:613)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:446)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
       at android.content.res.Resources.createFromResourceStream(Resources.java:2813)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2514)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2416)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:393)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:751)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3740)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:139)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:60)
       at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:56)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1017)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1076)
       at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:729)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
       at demand.inn.com.quflip.activity.ProductInfoActivity.onCreate(ProductInfoActivity.java:73)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Now how should I optimize the resources so that I can get rid of this error?

Should I resize the images on the server or should I resize them inside my app to get free from all these. 
Currently, I am using picasso to load the images inside my app.

Comment: It will be better to resize the images from the server.. which will also reduces the network consumption.

Comment: Can yo please show your dependencies in gradle file?

Comment: The stacktrace doesn't say you're using Picasso. The error is in an XML drawable on an ImageView

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to load 15694612 bytes = 15 MB weigh image, which is too big. If there is no option to have a separate downsampled resource, then your option is to [downsample it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17773344/1083957) and then load it.

```
private Bitmap downscaleBitmapUsingDensities(final int sampleSize, final int imageResId) {
  final Options bitmapOptions = new Options();
  bitmapOptions.inDensity = sampleSize;
  bitmapOptions.inTargetDensity = 1;
  final Bitmap scaledBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imageResId, bitmapOptions);
  scaledBitmap.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
  return scaledBitmap;
}
```

`sampleSize` is an integer which specifies how many times you want the source bitmap to be downsampled before loading it into memory.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using picasso to load the images, you can get the bitmap from the picasso by using following code:

```
Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
           // do you compression logic here and apply that bitmap to image

            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };


void foo() {
        Picasso.with(getContext()).load(getUrl()).into(target);
}
```

The answer provided by @azizbekian will give you scaled version of image, you can further compress it by using simple code mentioned in [this link](https://gist.github.com/vipulasri/0cd97d012934531f1266), which considers the orientation, aspect ration of image too.